# error while using text function with lamdba

Tags: python, text, lambda, sentiment-analysis

i am trying to use this ready code i found it online on [github](https://github.com/xiaoqingwan/NLP-Emotion-Detection/blob/main/emotion_detection_nrclex.ipynb)

I installed all the packages:

```
pip install NRCLex
pip install textblob
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

And this is my code:

```
from nrclex import NRCLex

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

emotion = NRCLex(text)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df['emotions'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: NRCLex(x).affect_frequencies)
```

I face this error i this last line:

```
KeyError  Traceback (most recent call last)
File \~\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\indexes\\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3801 try:
\-\> 3802     return self.\_engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803 except KeyError as err:

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas_libs\\index.pyx:138, in pandas.\_libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas_libs\\index.pyx:165, in pandas.\_libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5745, in pandas.\_libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas_libs\\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5753, in pandas.\_libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'text'



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:



KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[39\], line 1
\----\> 1 df\['emotions'\] = df\['text'\].apply(lambda x: NRCLex(x).affect_frequencies)
2 df.head()


File \~\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\frame.py:3807, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
3805 if self.columns.nlevels \> 1:
3806     return self.\_getitem_multilevel(key)
\-\> 3807 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
3808 if is_integer(indexer):
3809     indexer = \[indexer\]


File \~\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\indexes\\base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3802     return self.\_engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3803 except KeyError as err:
\-\> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
3805 except TypeError:
3806     # If we have a listlike key, \_check_indexing_error will raise
3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
3808     #  the TypeError.
3809     self.\_check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: Please format your code. In order to show actualy code, unlike codeproject, this site uses triple backticks before and after the intended code. For example , `this is single line code`  (I used a single \`)and ```this is  multi-line code```(I used three `)

Comment: I did exactly like the code in the link i provided, but her i wrote for you the specific error i faced, i did actually multi-line code

Comment: @literallyGutsFromBerserk

Comment: It's just saying there is no column `'text'` in your dataframe.  What does `test.csv` look like?  Show is the first couple of lines.

Comment: Try finding out which keys the dataframe has by print(data.columns)

Comment: @nscholten  you're write i checked my csv file and i changed it to reviewText according to the column i referred to, so the new problem showing up that: TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>.

Comment: these are the columns : Index(['reviewerID', 'asin', 'reviewerName', 'reviewText', 'reviewTime'], dtype='object')

Comment: Can you try changing `NRCLex(text)` to `NRCLex()`? Also, when looking at the github it doesn't look like the lambda expression will work. But let's try.